scrollbar-gutter оставляет белую полосу
Если прописать фон на body, то такой же будет применён к html и вьюпорту:


body {
  background: silver;
}
Hi!



Но если на html написать scrollbar-gutter: stable, то на месте, отведённом под скроллбар, получается белая полоса, т. е. браузер не применяет фон к вьюпорту. Как покрасить эту полосу?


html {
  scrollbar-gutter: stable;
}

body {
  background: silver;
}
<details>
  <summary>Expand...</summary>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore iure eligendi incidunt sunt possimus inventore, impedit non doloremque soluta excepturi dolorum, cumque quasi veritatis doloribus architecto corporis maxime. Tenetur, corrupti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore iure eligendi incidunt sunt possimus inventore, impedit non doloremque soluta excepturi dolorum, cumque quasi veritatis doloribus architecto corporis maxime. Tenetur, corrupti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore iure eligendi incidunt sunt possimus inventore, impedit non doloremque soluta excepturi dolorum, cumque quasi veritatis doloribus architecto corporis maxime. Tenetur, corrupti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore iure eligendi incidunt sunt possimus inventore, impedit non doloremque soluta excepturi dolorum, cumque quasi veritatis doloribus architecto corporis maxime. Tenetur, corrupti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore iure eligendi incidunt sunt possimus inventore, impedit non doloremque soluta excepturi dolorum, cumque quasi veritatis doloribus architecto corporis maxime. Tenetur, corrupti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore iure eligendi incidunt sunt possimus inventore, impedit non doloremque soluta excepturi dolorum, cumque quasi veritatis doloribus architecto corporis maxime. Tenetur, corrupti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore iure eligendi incidunt sunt possimus inventore, impedit non doloremque soluta excepturi dolorum, cumque quasi veritatis doloribus architecto corporis maxime. Tenetur, corrupti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore iure eligendi incidunt sunt possimus inventore, impedit non doloremque soluta excepturi dolorum, cumque quasi veritatis doloribus architecto corporis maxime. Tenetur, corrupti!
</details>  




Хромопроблемы, в моём Firefox всё ок

...зато если добавить ещё и background-image, то в Firefox получаются одновременно фон с картинкой и серая полоска справа, забавно

@andreymal, про твой FF не знаю, но мой делает оверлейный скроллбар, а в таком случае отступ 0. А вот сафари на маке (с включенными в системе скроллами) ведёт себя так же, как хром - пустая полоса справа.

Как вариант попробуйте накинуть background на html, а не на body

@DeniskaSosiSka спецификация говорит, что оба эти варианта должны давать идентичный результат (и я проверял, действительно идентичные)

@Qwertiy поэтому я оверлейный скроллбар предусмотрительно отключил)



* {
    scrollbar-color: #d0dee2 silver;
}
html {
  scrollbar-gutter: stable;
}

body {
  background: silver;
}
<details>
  <summary>Expand...</summary>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore iure eligendi incidunt sunt possimus inventore, impedit non doloremque soluta excepturi dolorum, cumque quasi veritatis doloribus architecto corporis maxime. Tenetur, corrupti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore iure eligendi incidunt sunt possimus inventore, impedit non doloremque soluta excepturi dolorum, cumque quasi veritatis doloribus architecto corporis maxime. Tenetur, corrupti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore iure eligendi incidunt sunt possimus inventore, impedit non doloremque soluta excepturi dolorum, cumque quasi veritatis doloribus architecto corporis maxime. Tenetur, corrupti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore iure eligendi incidunt sunt possimus inventore, impedit non doloremque soluta excepturi dolorum, cumque quasi veritatis doloribus architecto corporis maxime. Tenetur, corrupti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore iure eligendi incidunt sunt possimus inventore, impedit non doloremque soluta excepturi dolorum, cumque quasi veritatis doloribus architecto corporis maxime. Tenetur, corrupti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore iure eligendi incidunt sunt possimus inventore, impedit non doloremque soluta excepturi dolorum, cumque quasi veritatis doloribus architecto corporis maxime. Tenetur, corrupti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore iure eligendi incidunt sunt possimus inventore, impedit non doloremque soluta excepturi dolorum, cumque quasi veritatis doloribus architecto corporis maxime. Tenetur, corrupti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore iure eligendi incidunt sunt possimus inventore, impedit non doloremque soluta excepturi dolorum, cumque quasi veritatis doloribus architecto corporis maxime. Tenetur, corrupti!
</details>  




В своём хроме по-прежнему наблюдаю белую полосу на месте скроллбара

@andreymal, зато скроллбар перекрасился под фон...

Белая полоска появляется только во фрейме. Это - цвет фона фрейма. Если показывать без фрейма, то никаких белых полосок не появляется.

А и правда. Однако тогда получается, что и scrollbar-color не нужен (а ещё background-image всё равно коряво работает)

Хм.. Без iframe цвет действительно применяется, а вот градиент - уже нет. data:text/html,<!doctype html><style>html { scrollbar-gutter: stable; } body { background: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue, white) red; }</style><p>123: https://i.sstatic.net/KNNMrAGy.png
